# CNTK output for image to image comparison

Tags: cntk

I would like to manipulate the CNTK output to show which images were classified incorrectly vs those that were classified correctly. 
Currently I have the standard output of: “Final Results: Minibatch[1-190]: errs = 86.053% * 380” after my test run. 
Where would I look in order to create my own output report so that I can see the results of what my network labeled each image?

Answer (score 2):

You could run the model through the `eval` function on the learnt model. Get the labels and compare against the test labels.

There is example in CNTK 201: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.ipynb

In the code below, you can provide the test images and compare the generated target values with the ground truth labels.

```
import PIL
def eval(pred_op, image_path):
    label_lookup =     print("Top 3 predictions:")
    for i in range(top_count):["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]
    image_mean   = 133.0
    image_data   = np.array(PIL.Image.open(image_path), dtype=np.float32)
    image_data  -= image_mean
    image_data   = np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(image_data, (2, 0, 1)))

    result       = np.squeeze(pred_op.eval({pred_op.arguments[0]:[image_data]}))

    # Return top 3 results:
    top_count = 3
    result_indices = (-np.array(result)).argsort()[:top_count]


        print("\tLabel: {:10s}, confidence: {:.2f}%".format(label_lookup[result_indices[i]], result[result_indices[i]] * 100))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Azure notebook to be able to compare this example with the code I have on my desktop.
The Python function you are referencing for eval I have in a cntk file. 
Is there a place where I can see the Azure code from scratch?

Comment: In other words, how do I get this to run on my own computer instead of having to use Azure?
Thanks!

Comment: Azure notebook is a free service for educational purposes. It comes bundled with data. For running the code on your own data, you need to install CNTK in your local machine (using the setup instructions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine)or cloud instances of VMs running Windows / Linux. Azure DSVMs (a pay per use service) comes pre-installed with CNTK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-provision-vm. Also, for image related task having GPU is highly recommended.